# Moving a table within my div tag with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have gotten my web page blocked out with CSS and here is the issue I am having, I want to just move the table of URL's to a more centered and lower position within the 'right' div tag.  the colors are just for differentiation of field. ignore the img links.

This is the html code (for this assignment I am not allowed to use anything other than CSS and HTML. Below this code is the CSS file.

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Town of Oz Info</title>
        <meta name="Zachary" content="Zachary Maltais" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oz.css" />
        <!-- Date: 2012-09-05 -->
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--Using a div based layout to position things on the page -->

        <div id="header">
            <!-- header code goes here -->

            <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to Town of Oz</h1>

        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <!-- All main content go here -->

        </div>

        <div id="right">
            <!-- right side of screen code goes here -->

            <!-- Table for navigation -->
            <table id="navigation">
                <tr>
                    <th><img src="images/arrow.gif"></th>
                    <th><a href="home.html">Home</a></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><img src="images/arrow.gif"></th>
                    <th><a href="events.html">Events</a></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><img src="images/arrow.gif"></th>
                    <th><a href="directions.html">Directions</a></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><img src="images/arrow.gif"></th>
                    <th><a href="weather.html">Weather</a></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><img src="images/arrow.gif"></th>
                    <th><a href="wizards.html">Wizards</a></th>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div id="left">
            <!-- left side of screen code goes here -->
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <!-- footer code goes here-->

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#page {
    max-width: 950px;
    max-height: 720px;
}

#header {
    background: #ff9999;
    position: absolute;
    width: 950px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#content {
    background: #9999ff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 750px;
    height: 550px;
}

#right {
    background: #ffff99;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    height: 550px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#footer {
    background: #99ff99;
    position: absolute;
    top: 650px;
    width: 950px;
    height: 70px;
}

#navigation {
    position:absolute;
    top:200;
    left:50;
    border:dotted;
    border-color: black; 
}
#welcome {
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-size: 250%;
    font-family: "Perpetua";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: If someone wants the Fiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/JdWfB/

Comment: I am missing the px within the navigation, doh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**, i little changes to your ccs for the #navigation

```
#navigation {
    border:dotted;
    border-color: black;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
```

just change the top value if you want to put it down.

Comment: What does the margin:0px auto; do in this situation, I am having a little trouble understanding margins within the divs i have set up.

Comment: it will set the left and right margin to auto, to make it centered, 0px is for top margin and auto is for the left and right margin.

Comment: or if dont want to use margin.. you can use `left: ;` put a value, to make it centered..

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I have gotten to a point in my project where I can go to bed happy.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this rule for the css

```
#right table{margin: 20px;}
```

Comment: I can name the div tag and then an element in css? I didn't know that.  I have to say this project is all css and I am loving the power it has.

Comment: if you want you could make something like: div#right table{margin:20px} - If you use class properties you could make something like div.myClass or just .myClass{ css properties }